# Get all vector elements between different indices

Tags: matlab, vector

I have one vector of starting points (`start`) and another vector for end points (`end`):

> start=[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
>   end=  [0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]

I want a third vector `A` all the numbers between each start and endpoint.

> A =  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3]

so the result for this example could look like this:

> A_result= [1 2 3 5 6 7 9 1 2]

any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid I can not fully understand your question. How exactly do your 'start' and 'end' vectors represent the starting/end points? What's the realtion between 'A' and 'A_Result'?

Comment: @McMa If i understood him right, he wants to copy all `A(idx)` to his result from a  `1` in vector `start` til a `1` in vector `end`. At least this would match up to his result.

Comment: Looks like you did ;)

Comment: BTW, please avoid naming your variables as Matlab reserved words, like `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check the solution from seb it is way faster for large arrays.**

This is a solution using a `for-loop`

```
d_start=[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0];
d_end= [0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0];
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3];

starting_idx = find(d_start);
ending_idx = find(d_end);

A_result = [];
for l=1:numel(starting_idx)
    A_result=horzcat(A_result, A(starting_idx(l):ending_idx(l)));
end
```

What I am doing is: 1. I get the index of the starting and end points (`find`). Then i predefine my result. Now i just have to loop over the number of entries in the starting points and add those values from that position to next ending to my result.

**Edit: Timing test:**
I used my solution as well as the solution from seb (modified to my variable names):

```
mask = cumsum(d_start)-cumsum([0 d_end(1:end-1)]);
B_res =A(find(mask));
```

as well as my comment to his solution:

```
mask = cumsum(d_start)-cumsum([0 d_end(1:end-1)]);
B_res =A(mask==1);
```

These were the timing results for  `A:[12888x1]double`

```
t_forloop : 33 sec
t_seb_find: 0.31 sec
t_seb_logical: 0.1964 sec
```

Answer (score 4):

Without loop:

```
s=[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0];
e=[0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0];
mask = cumsum(s)-cumsum([shift(e,1)])
# Will be  [1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0]

A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3];
A(find(mask))
# will be  [1   2   3   5   6   7   9   1   2]
```

Or as **The Minion** pointed out, simply:

```
A(mask==1)
# will be  [1   2   3   5   6   7   9   1   2]
```

Comment: really nice solution, You could also use `mask==1` instead of `find(mask)` not sure which one is faster/better. Anyway +1

Comment: I don't think `mask==1` will return me indexes like 1 2 3... Hence I used `find()`, but there might indeed be a faster way than find.

Comment: It does, because it checks for each element if the line is true. You would have to use `Result=A(mask==1);` and if my timing test is right that would be fastest.